# Ubuntu slow after installing application on disk

Tags: partitioning

I have a 1TB SSD-HDD hybrid which has been partitioned in two. I have Ubuntu installed on one half and the other partition is for games which is install via Windows (which itself is on a separate disk).

When I install a new game to the disk that Ubuntu is on, Ubuntu and all applications are slow the first time I use them, but then return to normal on the second.

Is this the disc adjusting to the new install or is there something else going on here? I don't know why changes to the games partition would effect the Ubuntu on the other.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way your SS-HD works.

There is a really small SSD as "Cache", attached to a usual HDD.

So if you install a game, your SS-HD moves the game Data to the SSD Cache, and if you run the apps in Ubuntu, it copies the app data back to the ssd cache.

If you want real SSD performance, you will need to buy a real ssd.

Comment: OK thanks. I'm happy with the performance - just not straight after I'v installed a new game :)